# Unable to install tensorflow.js

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, npm

I am trying to install tensorflow.js on a windows machine using:

`npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu`

I am using python 2.7 and have tried updating npm.

Whenever I do that I get the following error:

```
Error: node-gyp rebuild failed with: Error: Command failed: node-gyp rebuild
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Coding\AI\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node-gpu
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: did you install the build tools?  npm install --global windows-build-tools

Comment: That doesn't help

Comment: make sure you give it enough time.  sometimes i had to run it several times for some reason to get everything installed.   anyway thats my experience with pre-req of node-gyp.  but then again. it might not be this problem

Comment: both tensorflow and tensorflow-node work but not tensorflow-node-gpu

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem on Mac. This [issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/809) on github points out that when you use this package `node-gyp` (which I think is a cross-platform tool used to help install Tensorflow), you need to make sure that your file path doesn't contain any spaces.

So, based on your error message, it looks like you are trying to install tensorflow in a project that is in the `Program Files\` folder. `node-gyp` doesn't like that because you have spaces in the name. It's kind of annoying, but I fixed the problem by putting my node project in a folder without spaces, i.e. `/Users/Bryce/Coding-Projects/MyProject/`

Comment: This works for the @tensorflow/tfjs-node package as well.

Such an odd issue. But thanks for the fix. It's working for me now.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
npm install @tensorflow/tfjs
```

You update npm package first:

```
 npm update
```

And upgrade:

```
 npm upgrade
```